# $content_var = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials',$param); return empty array

Tags: php

i'am using abraham's twitter oauth library for connecting and getting information. I'am able to authenticate but on callback url i'am using $params=$connection->get('account/verify_credentials',$param) which is returning an empty array.Please help...

Answer (score 0):

got the answer changed
public $host = "https://api.twitter.com/1/";  to public $host = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";